# Bridging ethers without private keys

Tags: layer-2, bridge, optimism

According to Optimism SDK [guide](https://docs.optimism.io/builders/dapp-developers/tutorials/cross-dom-bridge-eth) we should provide the Ethereum private key to generate an account on Optimism. If we were to apply this method to an crypto exchange that its wallet service is custodial, is there a way for that exchange to extract the private keys of its users' wallets or to use the guide using the parent wallet's mnemonic?